# Google Chrome 52 Embedded images not working on https

Tags: image, google-chrome, https

Since Chrome 52.0.2743.116(64bit) embedded image links do not work over https.
http works fine.
This is on a new Chrome installation with no addons.
Image added like below(base64 string not actual value, just a sample)

`<TR>
<TD ALIGN="center" width="30%"><IMG SRC="images.show?a=MTIzNDU="></TD>
</TR>`

Image headers as reported from Chrome:
`Cache-control:private,max-age=0,must-revalidate
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Disposition:filename="myimage.JPG"
Content-Language:en
Content-Length:31262
Content-Type:image/jpeg
Date:Wed, 17 Aug 2016 07:09:31 GMT
Expires:Thu, 01 Jan 1970 12:00:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=97`

Tried canary version 54, incognito mode, clear cache e.t.c same problem.

Note that IE, Edge, Firefox, Opera, Safari, Samsung Mobile Browser work fine.

Thank you